# FirebaseUI React: allow user to sign up via email+password without providing their first/last name

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the FirebaseUI React auth component so users can log in via email + password.

```
const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
  ]
};

....

<FirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
```

However, the registration form wants the user's first and last name.

[image: Screenshot of the FirebaseUI email+password login]

I don't want the user to provide this information at the time of registration. How do I customize the component to remove the name input from the registration flow?

Comment: You can clone, modify, and build a new library from the source code: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setRequireName` method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java#L635) seems to allow for this. Here is an example of the FirebaseUI demo application [using `setRequireName` to enable/disable this UI element](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/e9df5b55a5e83cea037f61188ce6dca3179a86d5/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/auth/AuthUiActivity.java#L392-L397):

```
if (mUseEmailProvider.isChecked()) {
    selectedProviders.add(new IdpConfig.EmailBuilder()
            .setRequireName(mRequireName.isChecked())
            .setAllowNewAccounts(mAllowNewEmailAccounts.isChecked())
            .build());
}
```